# How to host ClickOnce on AWS free of charge or with the minimum possible costs?

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, clickonce, .net-framework-version

I have a .NET Framework application and I want to host it for free or with minimal cost on AWS, what would be the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an S3 bucket to host a static site. So the simplest solution would be to setup the S3 bucket, setup a domain pointing to the bucket, and serve up the files for your ClickOnce distribution from that bucket. You may need to manually adjust some of the ContentType meta values on your files if S3 does not auto-detect them correctly.

You can read more about hosting static sites on S3 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

If it were me, I would setup an S3 bucket and then point a CloudFront distribution at that bucket. Both of these services have a free tier which should keep costs extremely minimal. The benefit of user CloudFront is that you will cut down on the S3 GetObject requests once it is cached in CloudFront and you should see a small performance improvement due to the distributed nature of CloudFront.

Take a look at this documentation for an example of using CloudFront and S3 together to serve up a static site. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

At my company, we host various production interfaces using this method and it works amazingly well.